# _CRT_RAND_S: How does it working in Windows C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, random

I wrote code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#define _CRT_RAND_S  // may this line cause problem
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    unsigned int r;
    rand_s(&r);

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

and compiler said, cannot find rand_s(). Then I switched line 1 and 2, it works.

```
#define _CRT_RAND_S
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
// ...
```

Question is,

1. Why do I have to define `_CRT_RAND_S` at the top of code?
2. Does `<iostream>` depends on `_CRT_RAND_S`? It seems not but...

I tried this in Windows x64, Visual Studio 2022. Thanks.

Comment: Standard library headers are allowed to include each other. It seems your `<iostream>` includes `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Please note that [`rand_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sxtz2fa8(v=vs.140)) is a MSVC-specific function, and not part of neither the C nor C++ standards. If you want to be portable and have good random-number generation then standard C++ have [lots of PRNG functionality](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), much better than `rand` or `rand_s`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is. `iostream` > `istream` > `ostream` > `ios` > `xlocnum` has `<cstdlib>`. Thank you.

Comment: Generally, I really recommend you to *not* use the "safe" functions (the ones with the `_s` suffix), not even the ones that exists in standard C. Because while it was Microsoft that forced these to be added, the MSVC implementations too often differ from the C standard functions. If you use any of them, you're locked into a MSVC-environment.

Comment: The shown code definitely can't be tagged as C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's why I cannot find `rand_s` in any other reference site? Then why `stdlib.h` include `rand_s()`? It's not C Standard? or It customized by MS?

Comment: A compiler and library implementer can add whatever non-standard things they please to standard header files.

Comment: Identifiers including macros that start with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for use by the compiler implementation.  You're not supposed to use them.

Comment: @MarkRansom The manual says to define it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/rand-s?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do I have to define `_CRT_RAND_S` at the top of code?

According to the documentation:

> The `_CRT_RAND_S` constant must be defined before the `stdlib.h` header for the `rand_s` function is included, ...

And to make sure that happens, you must define it before including any other header files, because header files (even the standard header files) are allowed to include other header files.

2. Does `<iostream>` depends on `_CRT_RAND_S`? It seems not but...

Most probably not, but `iostream` most probably includes `stdlib.h`, either directly or indirectly.